# How to manually install Android SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I have installed Android Studio. When I run it then it automatically tries to download Android SDK and due to firewall problem it is unable to download.
Is there any way to manually download and install this SDK so Android Studio doesn't have to download it automatically?
I am unable to go past this step because if I click cancel then Android Studio closes. Screenshot given below.

[image]

**EDIT**

Folder structure screenshot below.
[image]

**EDIT**
SDK screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Cancel this open Android studio, then just change the sdk path in opened project

Comment: I don't have any opened project. This is the first time I am running Android Studio after install.

Comment: did you tried downloading updates directly from sdk manager in sdk folder ... ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using my old SDK downloaded in D:\ and I update it whenever I need.

Comment: @Darkie There is no SDK folder or SDK manager here.

Comment: @FrankMartin there must be an SDK folder with your android studio installation. if there is not then how come it starts downloading the SDK. find that folder and run android.bat file in tools folder it will open up the SDK manager and you can download all the updates you want ... :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. There is no SDK folder that's why it is downloading SDK otherwise why would it download? Folder structure screenshot updated in original post above.

Comment: Ok now I got what you were saying. I had downloaded SDK separately but forgot :P  
I can see that it contain SDK Manager. But when I run it, it just download a few files and that's it. What do I do next? Screenshot updated above.

Comment: I think an easier solution is to fix the connection...use a VPN or proxy.

Comment: I am using proxy in browser but somehow Android Studio is unable to use it.

Comment: Create and set the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable to the root of your SDK folder.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. Set a system variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

When you see the above screen(in the screenshot you gave) then press cancel and it will show you "nothing was installed blah blah..." then don't click finish instead click the Close(x) box then you will see the Android Studio Menu from there go to "Configure" from there you can find some option related to SDK path

Comment: Thanks. This helped. We didn't have to finish, instead close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Just skip this and create a project, then click on project structure from file menu and change sdk path

You can use your old Sdk or download manually a new one and specify its path

[image: Just skip this and create a project, then click on project structure from file menu a]

Comment: How do I create project? When I open Android Studio, it starts downloading SDK.

Comment: If you have alread a sdk copy that and paste in C:\Android\android-studio. I assume you have installed it in C: drive.

Comment: I have copied folder "android-sdk-windows" (which contain SDK Manager, ADK Manager etc.) inside Android Studio folder but still when I run it, it automatically tries to download SDK and fails.